# Of the repair jobs that Bennie’s Machine Shop receives, 20 percent are

Tags: probability

I am a student and while doing an exercise along with with my friends, given in my book Discrete Event System Simulation by Banks, I got a doubt. I have searched similar questions in internet and got the following question.

> Of the repair jobs that Bennie’s Machine Shop receives, 20 percent are
>   welding jobs and 80 percent are machining jobs.
>
> (a) What is the probability that the next three jobs to come in will
>   be welding jobs?
>
> (b) What is the probability that two of the next three jobs to come in
>   will be the machining jobs?

I got a ppt from [b1.rimg.tw/kochente/9a40d391.ppt](http://b1.rimg.tw/kochente/9a40d391.ppt) in which the folling solution is given

> P(A) = 0.2 Thus P(A)xP(A)xP(A) = 0.2 x 0.2 x 0.2 = 0.008
>
> P(B) = 0.8 Thus P(B)xP(B)xP(B) = 0.8 x 0.8 x 0.8 = 0.512

But we felt this answer is wrong for P(B) because P(A) and P(B) cannot be calculated in similar ways.

We have posted the question in this  [website](http://goo.gl/1sPFUS)  for clarification. But the explanation I got there is given below

> "The question is not accurate and the following interpretations are
>   possible and went on to explain each case with binomial distribution
>   and obtained the following answers "
>
> Probability that the next three jobs will be welding jobs = 1/125
>
> Probability that exactly two of the next three jobs will be machining
>   jobs =48/125
>
> Probability that at least two of the next three jobs will be machining
>   jobs =112/125

With all these, I have now the following doubts. Please help in a way I can easily understand.

(1) The question is taken from my text book and should be correct. Then,
why the latter site explained the following statement as ambiguous

> "What is the probability that two of the next three jobs to come in
>   will be the machining jobs?"

and explained each of the following instead

> Case 1: Probability that exactly two of the next three jobs to come in
>   will be machining jobs
>
> Case 2: Probability that at least two of the next three jobs to come
>   in will be machining jobs

who is right here? What are the difference between these statements?
what is the right answer and right approach? Or the first solution i gave (taken from the ppt) is right ? If you can guide and show me the right path, I can try hard and study these which will be helpful in my studies.

(2) The latter site gives a concept of binomial distribution. I guess they have made it complex.  Is it relevant for this? if yes, where I can study more about it?

Thanks in advance. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Of the repair jobs that Bennie’s Machine Shop receives, 20 percent are welding jobs and 80 percent are machining jobs.
>
> (a) What is the probability that the next three jobs to come in will be welding jobs?

**If** (big, big **if**) all jobs are *independent*, i.e. no matter what previous jobs were, next one has the same probability to be a welding job which equals given frequency, $P(a) = P(${job 1 will be a welding job}$)*P(${job 2 will be a welding job}$)*P(${job 3 will be a welding job}$) = 0.2^3 = 0.008$.

> Case 1: Probability that exactly two of the next three jobs to come in will be machining jobs
>
> Case 2: Probability that at least two of the next three jobs to come in will be machining jobs
>
> What are the difference between these statements?

Suppose next three jobs are all machining jobs. This satisfies case 2, but not case 1.
For case 1 (with the same **if** as above), there are following sequences of jobs that fit ($w$ is wielding job and $m$ is machining job): $wmm, mwm, mmw$. Their probabilities are the same, $P(wmm)=P(mwm)=P(mmw)=0.8*0.8*0.2 = 0.128$. $P(${case 1}$)=P(wmm)+P(mwm)+P(mmw)=3*0.128=0.384$.

For case 2, fourth sequence appears: $mmm, P(mmm)=0.8^3=0.512$. So, $P(${case 2}$) = 3*0.2^1*0.8^2+1*0.2^0*0.8^3 = 0.896$.

Now some general info. When you have two mutually exclusive outcomes ($m$ and $w$, in our case), $p$ and $q=1-p$ are often used for their probabilities (for historical reasons). Then, probability of first outcome happening *exactly* $k$ times out of $n$ is $p^kq^{n-k}$ (probability of a single such outcome) multiplied by a number of such possible outcomes. Number of ways to choose $k$ unordered elements out of $n$ has special name, *binomial coefficient*, which is usually written $\binom{n}{k}$ or sometimes $C_n^k$ and calculated by formula $n! \over k!(n-k)!$. For our example, $\binom{3}{1}=3$, $\binom{3}{0}=1$.

Comment: in my text, the question is  just " What is the probability that two of the next three jobs to come in will be the machining jobs". Does this mean case 1 or case 2 ?

Comment: @user300718 This is linguistics question, not mathematics question. As a non-native speaker, I can only say that *to me* your question seems ambiguous and if I were to answer on such question, I would provide both solutions.

Comment: thanks a lot for clarifications